# Generate "duplicate" row if between a date there is more than one month involved

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm asked to "automatize" some Excel tasks regarding medical licenses, what I mainly need right now is to identify if a license is longer than a month period, if so, duplicate the entire row data besides the date which needs to be adapted on the "next month" and also generate a period id that includes the year + month (e.g. 201801 for a license started in Jan/2018).

What I did first was checking and displaying if a license is longer than x period (did a loop that counts days and identify if it matches with the month above the cell), so if one started on Jan and ended in Feb it would show like this:

```
period id   member  start date  end date    jan feb
201801  john doe    09/01/2018  07/02/2018  23  7

=SUMAPRODUCTO(--(TEXTO(FILA(INDIRECTO($J9 & ":" & SI($K9="";HOY();$K9)));"MMM")=N$8))
```

The problem with the table above is that the file becomes humongous with the formula, so instead I'm thinking, for now, just the row duplication:

```
period id   member  start date  end date    
201801  john doe    09/01/2018  31/01/2018      
201802  john doe    01/02/2018  07/02/2018
```

The thing is I can't figure how to compare months and print them the way I have to.

```
Sub CopyData()
Set hojatst = Sheets(Hoja5)
Dim d
Dim j
d = 1
j = 8
Do Until IsEmpty(hojatst.Range("D" & j))
    If hojatst.Range("D" & j) < hojatst.Range("E" & j) Then
    d = d + 1
    
    End If
    j = j + 1
End Sub
```

Comment: Please post your code and be specific as to what is not working properly in it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a 'sketch' of the code you will need to write. Stackoverflow is not a code request service and so you need to do your best to write it yourself. The community is happy to help you troubleshoot while you learn, but you should be using Google a lot. I wrote out the sketch to get you started because I remember how hard it was to learn the basics of coding. Feel free to ask clarifying questions.

First of all I cannot get Excel to recognize the DD/MM/YYYY format. It might be because mine is a US copy and that is not a standard time format here. You seem to be using a different version of Excel due to the formulas you listed. However be sure to double check that your code is correctly reading the DD/MM/YYYY format as you proceed.

Create a variable `cl` that is your current line. Create `md` which is the month difference.

If `Month (Start Date)` is less than `Month(End Date)` Then `md = Difference of Months`, insert that many lines below the current line. `Range("E" & cl+md).Value = Range("E" & cl)`which pastes your end date to the last slot.

Then for `cl < cl+md` fill in the periods by add +1 to the value if the last number is not 4 and +97 if it is.

Then fill in the blank cells for the dates with the `Start of Month` and `End of Month` dates.

Finally set `cl = cl + md + 1` and `loop` to move on to the next 'original' line.